# more than one count* sql in a single sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i want to use these sql statement as a single statement which will result in 4columns with different count and a company_id.

```
select company_id,count(*) as det from feedbacks a join( select id,company_id from users  ) b on a.user_id = b.id where healthi_rating < 7 group by company_id
select company_id,count(*) as neu from feedbacks a join( select id,company_id from users  ) b on a.user_id = b.id where healthi_rating <9 && healthi_rating >=7 group by company_id
select company_id,count(*) as pro from feedbacks a join( select id,company_id from users  ) b on a.user_id = b.id where healthi_rating >=9 group by company_id
```

can someone let me know how to do this.

Comment: Subqueries should work fine: `SELECT company_id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedbacks … where healthi_rating < 7 group by company_id) det, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedbacks …) neu`

Comment: can you tell me any other way to do this? or if you know by Active record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MySQL do

```
select company_id,
       sum(healthi_rating < 7) as det,
       sum(healthi_rating between 7 and 8) as neu,
       sum(healthi_rating >= 9) as pro
from feedbacks a 
join( select id, company_id from users ) b on a.user_id = b.id 
group by company_id
```

and using ANSI SQL Standard and without the subquery of `users`

```
select b.company_id,
       sum(case when healthi_rating < 7 then 1 else 0 end) as det,
       sum(case when healthi_rating between 7 and 8 then 1 else 0 end) as neu,
       sum(case when healthi_rating >=9 then 1 else 0 end) as pro
from feedbacks a 
join users b on a.user_id = b.id 
group by b.company_id
```

Comment: This solution should also be much more efficient than subqueries or separate queries (unless the SQL engine is really a genious or unless you have enough RAM to cache the whole table).

Comment: thanku, it works very well. Can you please explain me too why you used sum for this command @juergen

Comment: The condition in the `SUM()` return ´1` if true and `0` if false. `sum` adds up those true cases. You can also use `count` but need to use `null` for the false cases instead if `0`

Comment: I also removed the subquery of users in the second query. It should be even faster